# If $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n$ is bounded, then $a_nb_n \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that: if $(a_n) \to 0$ and $(b_n)$ is bounded, then $(a_nb_n)\to 0$.

I know if a sequence is convergent, then it is bounded, but I do not know where to begin since I only know $(b_n)$ is bounded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to converge to 0? In particular what can you say about $a_n$ for large values of $n$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be such  that $-M< b_n<M$ for all $n$. Observe that $\lim_n a_n(-M)=0=\lim_na_n M$, the result follows from the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see why this is true from the first principles. Let $M$ be such that $|b_{n}|<M$ for all $n$. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, as $(a_n)\rightarrow0$ there exists a $N_{\epsilon}$ such that whenever $n > N_{\epsilon}$ we have $|a_n-0| < \epsilon/M$. And hence whenever $n > N_{\epsilon}$ we must also have $|a_nb_n - 0| = |a_nb_n| < M|a_n| <M(\epsilon/M) = \epsilon$